# when to quote symbol in Emacs Lisp

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

I've beginning learning programming with Emacs Lisp. I'm so confused by symbol quotation.
For example:

```
(progn
  (setq a '(1 2))
  (prin1 a)
  (add-to-list 'a 3)
  (prin1 a)
  (setcar a 4)
  (prin1 a)
  (push 5 a)
  ""
)
```

why the "add-to-list" function need a quoted symbol as its first argument, while the "setcar" and "push" function need no argument quotation?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's a diagram that represents the symbol `a` and its value after `(setq a '(1 2))`. The boxes are elementary data structures (symbols and conses) and the arrows are pointers (where a piece of data references another). (I'm simplifying a little.)

```
 symbol                     cons              cons
+-------+----------+       +------+------+   +------+------+
|name:  |variable: |       |car:  |cdr:  |   |car:  |cdr:  |
| a     |    |     |       | 1    |  |   |   | 2    | nil  |
+-------+----|-----+       +------+--|---+   +------+------+
             |             ​↑         |       ↑
             +-------------+         +-------+
```

The expression `'(1 2)` builds the two conses on the right, which make up a two-element list. The expression `(setq a '(1 2))` creates the symbol `a` if it doesn't exist, then makes its “variable slot” (the part that contains the value of the symbol) point to the newly created list. `setq` is a built-in macro, and `(setq a '(1 2))` is shorthand for `(set 'a '(1 2))`. The first argument of `set` is the symbol to modify and the second argument is the value to set the symbol's variable slot to.

`(add-to-list 'a 3)` is equivalent to `(set 'a (cons 3 a))` here, because 3 is not in the list. This expression does four things:

1. Create a new cons cell.
2. Set the new cons cell's car field to `3`.
3. Set the new cons cell's cdr field to the former (and still current) value of `a` (i.e. copy the contents of `a`'s variable slot).
4. Set the variable slot of `a` to the new cons cell.

After that call, the data structures involved look like this:

```
 symbol                     cons              cons              cons
+-------+----------+       +------+--|---+   +------+------+   +------+------+
|name:  |variable: |       |car:  |cdr:  |   |car:  |cdr:  |   |car:  |cdr:  |
| a     |    |     |       | 3    |  |   |   | 1    |  |   |   | 2    | nil  |
+-------+----|-----+       +------+--|---+   +------+--|---+   +------+------+
             |             ​↑         |       ↑         |       ↑
             +-------------+         +-------+         +-------+
```

The call to `setcar` doesn't create any new data structure, and doesn't act on the symbol `a` but on its value, which is the cons cell whose `car` currently contains 3. After `(setcar a 4)`, the data structures look like this:

```
 symbol                     cons              cons              cons
+-------+----------+       +------+--|---+   +------+------+   +------+------+
|name:  |variable: |       |car:  |cdr:  |   |car:  |cdr:  |   |car:  |cdr:  |
| a     |    |     |       | 4    |  |   |   | 1    |  |   |   | 2    | nil  |
+-------+----|-----+       +------+--|---+   +------+--|---+   +------+------+
             |             ​↑         |       ↑         |       ↑
             +-------------+         +-------+         +-------+
```

`push` is a macro; here, `(push 5 a)` is equivalent to `(set 'a (cons 5 a))`.

`setq` and `push` are macros (`setq` is a “special form”, which as far as we're concerned here means a macro whose definition is built into the interpreter and not provided in Lisp). Macros receive their arguments unevaluated and can choose to expand them or not. `set`, `setcar` and `add-to-list` are functions, which receive their arguments evaluated. Evaluating a symbol returns the contents of its variable slot, e.g. after the initial `(setq a '(1 2))` the value of the symbol `a` is the cons cell whose car contains `1`.

If you're still confused, I suggest experimenting with `(setq b a)` and seeing for yourself which of the expressions modify `b` when you act on `a` (the ones that act on the symbol `a`) and which don't (the ones that act on the value of the symbol `a`).

Answer (score 13):

Functions evaluate their arguments before execution, so quote when you need to pass an actual symbol (as pointer to some data structure, for example) and don't quote when it's a variable value.

`add-to-list` performs in-place mutation of its first argument, so it needs a quoted symbol.

`push` is not a function, but a macro; that is why it's able to accept unquoted arguments without evaluation. Builtin forms, like `setcar`, also do not have that limitation.

Comment: Can you tell if something is a macro or a function purely from its documentation without looking at the implementation?

Comment: @Tom documentation usually states that right away in the first line (for push — `push is a Lisp macro in \`cl.el'.`).

Comment: Yes, but what about setcar? How do you know from the documentation that it doesn't evaluate its argument?

Comment: @Tom `setcar` is an ordinary function, and does evaluate its argument. A function or subr evaluates its arguments normally. A macro or special form can do whatever it wants.

Comment: Normally, the `q` suffix stands for "quoted": it automatically quotes the argument. So you have `setq` as set-quoted. If you used `set`, you should have quoted the argument: `(set 'a '(1 2))`

Answer (score 9):

The other answers given so far clarify the use of `quote` and the difference between *functions*, on the one hand, and *macros* and *special forms* on the other hand.

However, they do not get to another part of the question: *why* is `add-to-list` as it is? *Why* does it require its first argument to be a ***symbol***? That's a separate question from whether or not it evaluates the argument. It's the real question behind the design of `add-to-list`.

One could *imagine* that `add-to-list` evaluated its args, and expected the value of the first arg to be a list, and then added the value of the second arg to that list as an element and returned the result (new list or same list). That would let you do `(add-to-list foo 'shoe)` to add the symbol `shoe` to the list that is the value of `foo` -- say `(1 2 buckle)` --, to give `(1 2 buckle shoe)`.

The point is that such a function *would not be very useful*. Why? Because the list value isn't necessarily accessible. The variable `foo` might be thought of as a way to access it -- a "handle" or "pointer" to it.  But that is not true of the list that the function *returns*. That returned list can be composed of new list structure, and there is typically nothing (no variable) pointing to that list.  The function `add-to-list` never sees the symbol (variable) `foo` -- it has no way of knowing that the list value it receives as first argument is bound to `foo`.  If `add-to-list` were designed that way then you would still need to assign its returned result to your list variable.

IOW, `add-to-list` evaluates its args because it is a function, but that doesn't explain much. It expects a ***symbol*** as the value of its first arg.  And it expects the value of that variable (symbol) to be a list.  It adds the value of its second arg to the list (possibly changing the list structure), and it ***sets the value of the variable*** that is the value of its first arg to that list.

Bottom line: It needs a symbol as arg because its job is to ***assign a new value to that symbol*** (the new value being the same list value or the same value with the new list element added at the front).

And yes, another way to go would be to use a macro or special form, as in `push`.  It's the same idea: `push` wants a *symbol* as its second arg.  The difference is that `push` does not evaluate its args so the symbol need not be quoted.  But in both cases (in Emacs Lisp) the code needs to get hold of a *symbol* in order to *set its value* to the augmented list.

Comment: I do think that's a worthwhile point in general, but it's not really true in the case of lists, given that they are just pointers to a cons cell. For instance, consider `(defun my-add-to-list1 (list value) (setcdr (last list) (cons value nil)) list)` or `(defun my-add-to-list2 (list value) (setcdr list (cons (car list) (cdr list))) (setcar list value) list)`

Comment: The point was not that you cannot have a function that adds a value to a list that is not the value of a symbol. The point is that the point of `add-to-list` is to add an element to the list value of a variable. IOW, `add-to-list` is *all about setting a variable value*. It is ***not*** just a function to add an element to a list (in spite of its name).

Comment: I guess the important difference is that by passing the *symbol* you gain the ability to change the value of that symbol *without affecting the values of other symbols*, whereas if you pass the evaluated list itself, then all symbols pointing to that list may be affected.